# Edit Shared Libraries of Binary Mach-O MacOS

Tags: macos, binary, mach-o

I am trying to edit the shared libraries of a MacOS program in the Mach-O format, something like how patchelf works on linux. Is there a way to do this?

For example, I would like to change

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1161.21.3)`

(output from `otool -L`)

to a library at a different path in *just one binary*.

Thank you!

Comment: If you just want to change the path and don't care about the version information, see `man install_name_tool`.

Comment: I tried this but am now getting a very unhelpful `Killed: 9` error. Is this something to do with the program rejecting the modified library?

Comment: I guess that might've broken the code signature...? Try `codesign -f -s - path/to/modified/macho`...